# Geoserver init.d script

Tags: geoserver, ubuntu

I am trying to write an script which will start the Geoserver service on system boot. A good manual is given [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/linuxscript.html). I am on Ubuntu14.04 and using Geoserver-2.6.1.

I have edited the following lines accordingly, in this [script](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/_downloads/geoserver_deb).

```
USER=administrator
GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/home/$USER/geoserver-2.6.1/data_dir
GEOSERVER_HOME=/home/$USER/geoserver-2.6.1
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m"
```

When I am starting the service using the following command, it's giving an OK status.

```
administrator@abc:~# sudo service geoserver start
* Starting GeoServer daemon geoserver                                   [ OK ]
```

But can't open the manager webpage

```
http://localhost:8081/geoserver/web/
```

Plus, when I am trying to stop the service, the following Error is coming

```
administrator@abc:~# sudo service geoserver stop
* Stopping GeoServer daemon geoserver
No process in pidfile '/var/run/geoserver.pid' found running; none killed.
                                                                     [ OK ]
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Do you know if it's writing logs by default? Maybe somewhere in `/home/administrator/geoserver-2.6.1` there is some error log you can find. Another thing to do is try running the full command line (the `/usr/bin/java geoserver.jar etc`) as that user (rather than from init.d) and see if it outputs anything helpful.

Comment: There is a `logs` dir but the latest logs are not clear. Latest `logs` file is full of lines like `[24/Dec/2014:16:19:43 +0000] "GET /geoserver/web/resources/org.geoserver.web.GeoServerBasePage/img/page-bg.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2121` with 200 and 304 status. Plus, I didn't get your second approach? Could you please write the full command?

Comment: Maybe you could just install it on tomcat, which will make geoserver automatically start with tomcat.

Comment: @BradHards: This is what I am doing right now to keep myself going. But as my webapp.war file is also on the same Tomcat, I don't wanna use my 8080 port for both (webapp.war and geoserver.war). It's always better to keep the ports separate (am I right?). Another thing I can do is to install 2 tomcats (on port 8080 and 8081), one for the webapp.war and one for the geoserver.war. What would you suggest?

Comment: Don't expose tomcat to the outside. Run it behind a proxy server like nginx.

Comment: @BradHards: Thx a lot. I'll try to do that ASAP. Besides, do you think that running webapp.war (my web-app war file) and geoserver.war on one single Tomcat port is no harm? I was thinking that using one single port for everything may increase the traffic over that one (if the number of users increased with time) and reduce the speed and performance of the service.

Comment: Depends on load, but I wouldn't add complexity without metrics to show where the real bottleneck is.

Comment: Hmm.... I got your point. It's better to keep things simple at the beginning. I highly appreciate your words. Have a great festive day :)

Comment: Just experienced today. Keeping the port same for both webapp.war and geoserver.war reduced my service speed appreciably. When I am running on separate ports, I can see a good performance improvement. FYI.

Comment: Geoserver 2.14.2, jetty implementation, default paths, java-8-oracle, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: For me, geoserver web interface admin panel did'd start, even /etc/init.d/geoserver and /etc/default/geoserver are corect configured. I think the problem, described here is this, not that service did not start... Here are my logs and configurations: $sudo service geoserver status:
● geoserver.service - LSB: GeoServer OGC server Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/geoserver; generated) Active: active (exited) since Thu 2019-02-14 11:44:33 EET; 1min 29s ago Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8) Process: 855 ExecStart=/

Answer (score 9):

I found a working procedure:

1. Create a file `geoserver` inside `/etc/default` dir and feed with the following code (change top four variables according to your own setup):

   `USER=zia
   GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/home/$USER/Documents/Software/geoserver-2.6.1/data_dir
   GEOSERVER_HOME=/home/$USER/Documents/Software/geoserver-2.6.1
   JAVA_HOME=/usr
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m"`
2. Create another file `geoserver` inside `/etc/init.d` dir and feed with [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/_downloads/geoserver_deb) code. Change line 22 in this file according to your setup.
3. Being in `/etc/init.d` dir, make `geoserver` file executable using the following terminal command

   `sudo chmod +x geoserver`
4. Now you can start|stop the `geoserver` service using the following command

   `service geoserver start|stop`
5. In order to auto-start this service on system boot, run the following command being in the `/etc/init.d` dir

   `sudo update-rc.d geoserver defaults`
6. Visit the url in the browser to see Geoserver Admin page

Hope this to be useful.

Comment: Why do you need to change line 22 in `etc/init.d/geoserver` script? I guess, it's `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun` at the moment and used to define `DAEMON` variable. Due to all these variables are overrided by `/etc/default/geoserver` it's easy to add `DAEMON="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"` to the end of `/etc/default/geoserver` and don't make any changes in `/etc/init.d/geoserver` script.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Just note that if after step 4 you get an error saying `Failed to start geoserver.service: Unit geoserver.service not found.` A simple machine reboot fixed that for me.