# Why GeoServer data directory is "/usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/data" while path in config file is "/var/lib/geoserver_data"?

Tags: geoserver

I tried to change GeoServer data directory to `/var/lib/geoserver_data` and then I changed data directory in `/etc/init.d/geoserver` and `/etc/default/geoserver` to `/var/lib/geoserver_data` however I did define `var/lib/geoserver_data` as a default directory but I see default directory is `/usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/data`, I should mention this problem when happen my system runs GeoServer as service: If I stop GeoServer as a service and launch that by `sudo  ./startup.sh` I can see in my web administrator interface my default directory is `/var/lib/geoserver_data`, I am going to know how I can change `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIRECTORY` to `/var/lib/geoserver_data` instead of `/usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/data` when GeoServer is running as a service, This is my GeoServer config in `/etc/init.d/geoserver` and `/etc/default/geoserver` and GeoServer `web.xml`:

/etc/init.d/geoserver (shell script)

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          geoserver
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      S 0 1 6
# Short-Description: GeoServer OGC server
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Lennart Jütte <lenn@rtjuette.de>

# Geoserver configuration - use /etc/default/geoserver to override these vars
# user that shall run GeoServer
USER=sigma
GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/geoserver_data
GEOSERVER_HOME=/usr/share/geoserver

PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
DESC="GeoServer daemon"
NAME=geoserver
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

DAEMON="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
DAEMON_ARGS="$JAVA_OPTS $DEBUG_OPTS -DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=$GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar start.jar"

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
[ -f /etc/default/rcS ] && . /etc/default/rcS

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start(){
    
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started
    
    start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile \
        --chuid $USER --chdir $GEOSERVER_HOME \
        -b --test --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS > /dev/null \
        || return 1
        
    start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile \
        --chuid $USER --chdir $GEOSERVER_HOME \
        -b --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS \
        || return 2
}

do_stop(){
    
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred

    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile  $PIDFILE \
        --user $USER \
        --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5

    RETVAL="$?"
    [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
    
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return "$RETVAL"

}

case "$1" in
  start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_start
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0|1)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
            1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
            *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
        esac
        ;;
      *)
        # Failed to stop
        log_end_msg 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
  *)
    #echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

:
```

/etc/default/geoserver (shell scipt)

```
USER=sigma
GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/geoserver_data
GEOSERVER_HOME=/usr/share/geoserver/
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m"
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
    <display-name>GeoServer</display-name>
  
      <context-param>
    <param-name>serviceStrategy</param-name>
    <!-- Meaning of the different values :
         
         PARTIAL-BUFFER2
         - Partially buffers the first xKb to disk. Once that has buffered, the the 
           result is streamed to the user. This will allow for most errors to be caught
           early. 
           
         BUFFER
         - stores the entire response in memory first, before sending it off to
           the user (may run out of memory)

         SPEED
         - outputs directly to the response (and cannot recover in the case of an
           error)

         FILE
         - outputs to the local filesystem first, before sending it off to the user
      -->
    <param-value>PARTIAL-BUFFER2</param-value>
  </context-param>
  
  <context-param>
    <!-- see comments on the PARTIAL-BUFFER strategy -->
    <!-- this sets the size of the buffer.  default is "50" = 50kb -->

    <param-name>PARTIAL_BUFFER_STRATEGY_SIZE</param-name>
    <param-value>50</param-value>
  </context-param>
  
  <!--Can be true or false (defaults to: false). -->
  <!--When true the JSONP (text/javascript) output format is enabled -->
  <!--
  <context-param>
    <param-name>ENABLE_JSONP</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  -->
    <!-- 
    <context-param>
      <param-name>PROXY_BASE_URL</param-name>
      <param-value>http://82.58.146.45/geoserver</param-value>
    </context-param>
     -->
   
     
    <context-param>
       <param-name>GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR</param-name>
        <param-value>/var/lib/geoserver_data</param-value>
    </context-param> 
   
    
    <!-- pick up all spring application contexts -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:/applicationContext.xml classpath*:/applicationSecurityContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <filter>
     <filter-name>FlushSafeFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
     
    <filter>
      <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
     <filter-name>SessionDebugger</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>     
     <filter-class> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>xFrameOptionsFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

   <filter>
     <filter-name>GZIP Compression Filter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
         <!-- The compressed-types parameter is a comma-separated list of regular expressions.
              If a mime type matches any of the regular expressions then it will be compressed.
              -->
         <param-name>compressed-types</param-name>
         <param-value>text/.*,.*xml.*,application/json,application/x-javascript</param-value>
     </init-param>
   </filter>

   <filter>
     <filter-name>Request Logging Filter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
         <!-- The 'enabled' parameter is a boolean value, "true" (case-insensitive) for true or
              any other value for false.  If enabled, then the logging will be performed;
              otherwise the logging filter will have no effect.  If not specified, this 
              parameter defaults to false.
              -->
         <param-name>enabled</param-name>
         <param-value>false</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <!-- The 'log-request-headers' parameter is a boolean value, "true" (case-insensitive) for
              true or any other value for false.  If enabled, then the logging will include the HTTP 
              headers of requests.  If not specified, this parameter defaults to false.
              -->
         <param-name>log-request-headers</param-name>
         <param-value>false</param-value>
     </init-param>  
     <init-param>
     <!-- The 'log-request-bodies' parameter is a boolean value, "true" (case-insensitive) for
          true or any other value for false.  If enabled, then the logging will include the body
          of POST and PUT requests.  If not specified, this parameter defaults to false.
          Note that this may noticeably degrade responsiveness of your geoserver since it will
          not begin to process requests until the entire request body has been received by the 
          server.
          -->
     <param-name>log-request-bodies</param-name>
     <param-value>false</param-value>
     </init-param>
   </filter>
   
   <filter>
     <filter-name>Advanced Dispatch Filter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter</filter-class>
     <!-- 
     This filter allows for a single mapping to the spring dispatcher. However using /* as a mapping
     in a servlet mapping causes the servlet path to be "/" of the request. This causes problems with
     library like wicket and restlet. So this filter fakes the servlet path by assuming the first 
     component of the path is the mapped path. 
     -->
   </filter>
   
   <filter>
    <filter-name>Spring Delegating Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter</filter-class>
    <!--
    This filter allows for filters to be loaded via spring rather than 
    registered here in web.xml.  One thing to note is that for such filters 
    init() is not called. INstead any initialization is performed via spring 
    ioc.
    -->
   </filter>
   
   <filter>
     <filter-name>Thread locals cleanup filter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter</filter-class>
     <!-- 
     This filter cleans up thread locals Geotools is setting up for concurrency and performance
     reasons 
     -->
   </filter>

  <!--  Uncomment following filter to enable CORS -->
   <filter>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>chainPreflight</param-name>
           <param-value>false</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
           <param-value>*</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
           <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
           <param-value>*</param-value>
       </init-param>
    </filter>
   

    <!-- 
      THIS FILTER MUST BE THE FIRST ONE, otherwise we end up with ruined chars in the input from the GUI
      See the "Note" in the Tomcat character encoding guide:
      http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding
    -->
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
   
   <!-- Uncomment following filter to enable CORS -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
   
   
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>FlushSafeFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>SessionDebugger</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>GZIP Compression Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>xFrameOptionsFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Request Logging Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
   
    <!-- 
      If you want to use your security system comment out this one too
    -->
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Advanced Dispatch Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Spring Delegating Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Thread locals cleanup filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <!-- general initializer, should be first thing to execute -->
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <!-- logging initializer, should execute before spring context startup -->
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.geoserver.logging.LoggingStartupContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
  
    <!--  spring context loader -->
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <!--  http session listener proxy -->
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerHttpSessionListenerProxy</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- request context listener for session-scoped beans -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <!-- spring dispatcher servlet, dispatches all incoming requests -->
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    
    <!-- single mapping to spring, this only works properly if the advanced dispatch filter is 
         active -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <mime-mapping>
      <extension>xsl</extension>
      <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
      <extension>sld</extension>
      <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
      <extension>json</extension>
      <mime-type>application/json</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
  
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    
</web-app>
```

I installed These GeoServer extensions also:
GeoFence, Importer, CSW,Web Resources

Comment: Please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button - the most likely issue is that user `sigma` doesn't have write permission to the data directory while `root` does. The top of the log file will tell you.

Comment: I did login through web administrator interface, I checked log, it was empty!, When I changed my username to geoserver, web admin interface can't launch!,it work when my user is sigma(my computer user)

Comment: I changed my username due to question and its answer it was here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127569/geoserver-init-d-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GeoServer "daemon" must be run by a user that has write permission to the data directory you have specified. 
If it can not read & write to that file then it will switch to the default data directory.

This is why your set up works when you run it as `root` (i.e. `sudo  ./startup.sh`) since `root` can do anything it likes - that is why it is a very dangerous thing to run a service as `root` so don't do this in production.

You need to set up a user called `geoserver` and then run

```
sudo chown -R geoserver /var/lib/geoserver_data
```

to make sure it has the necessary ownership.
Then use this `geoserver` user in your startup script.