# Error in run GeoServer as a service

Tags: geoserver, web-service

I'm trying to run a GeoServer instance in Ubuntu 20.04 as a service, as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127569/geoserver-init-d-script).

When I run:

```
sudo service geoserver start
```

I get the error message:

```
Job for geoserver.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status geoserver.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then the systemctl command shows:

```
Jan 24 18:54:22 ip-172-31-8-31 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: GeoServer OGC server...
Jan 24 18:54:22 ip-172-31-8-31 geoserver[1171]: /etc/init.d/geoserver: 28: .: 3: Too many open files
Jan 24 18:54:22 ip-172-31-8-31 systemd[1]: geoserver.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jan 24 18:54:22 ip-172-31-8-31 systemd[1]: geoserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 24 18:54:22 ip-172-31-8-31 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: GeoServer OGC server.
```

How can I fix it?